# How to remove fade effect from horizontal menu

Tags: css, module, menu, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I can't reach my goal.
How can I remove that 'fastidious' fade effect from the PrestaShop menu, I've tried:

```
categoryMenu.superfish({
    animation : {display: 'block'}
});
```

without success. I use the default module to display the menu in the front-end

Comment: Sorry, what code do you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that initialization will not help you because it’s an option of superfish core.
To remove the fade effect you should edit this file: `superfish-modified.js`, this file is located in `default-bootstrap/js/modules/blocktopmenu/js/` if you have the default template.

You have to change this line #162 (for the fade-in):

```
$ul.stop(true, true).animate(o.animation, o.speed, function () {
```

In this:

```
$ul.stop(true, true).show(0, function () {
```

And this line #146 (for the fade-out):

```
$ul.stop(true, true).animate(o.animationOut, speed, function () {
```

In this:

```
$ul.stop(true, true).hide(0, function () {
```

And change your initialization in:

```
categoryMenu.superfish({
    delay : 1
});
```

Hope it helps ;)